# JavaScript replace in jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp-tags

I am facing a little problem in JavaScript.
I have a template that I use to add some fields to my form:

```
 <div id="personTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <s:url id="personneList" action="personneList" namespace="/ajax" />
    <sj:autocompleter name="personnesContacts[ID_XXX]"
        id="nomPersonne_IDXXX" forceValidOption="false"
        key="label.serviceContacts" href="%{personneList}" />
</div>
```

With jQuery, I get the content in my personTemplate div, which is :

```
<input id="nomPersonne_IDXXX" name="personnesContacts[1]" type="hidden">
<input autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input" name="personnesContacts[ID_XXX]_widget" id="nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget" type="text">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" aria-live="polite" role="status"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget = {};
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.hiddenid = "nomPersonne_IDXXX";
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.selectBox = false;
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.forceValidOption = false;

            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.jqueryaction = "autocompleter";
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.id = "nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget";
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.name = "personnesContacts[ID_XXX]_widget";
            options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget.href = "/baseline/ajax/personneList.action";
        jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget'),options_nomPersonne_IDXXX_widget);
    });
</script>
```

I tried to replace IDXXX by a number, but it is only in the name attribute that this occurrence is changed.
May be you have an idea of how to replace IDXXX when I get the div content like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
counter = 0;
function addMorePersons() {
    counter++;
    var text = $('#personTemplate').html();
    text = text.replace("ID_XXX", counter);
    $(text).insertAfter($('#personnesContact_0_widget'));

}
```

Comment: Please show _how_ you tried to replace IDXXX by a number.

Comment: I have edited the question to show how I tried to replace IDXXX by a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a global replace function, if you use a regular expression, you can tell it to replace all:

```
text = text.replace(/ID_XXX/g, counter);
```